# How to generate a unique device ID for Android app subscription without using Android ID or serial number?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application that requires users to send their backup code to activate their subscription via a server. The backup code is the same as the Android ID, but I have some security issues that prevent me from doing this. The only solution is to replace the Android ID with something else and that is to find another unique code for each device.

Except for the serial number of the phone, the rest are the same in all phones, similar to each other. And I can't get the serial number of the phone due to security issues. Another solution is to create an application token for the user, but this is also not possible because we have to update the application from scratch. Please give me a solutio
n.

I have mentioned it in the text of the question